# RESTservice, resource with two different outputs - how would you do it?

Tags: web-services, rest

Im currently working on a more or less RESTful webservice, a type of content api for my companys articles. We currently have a resource for getting all the content of a specific article

`http://api.com/content/articles/{id}`

will return a full set of article data of the given article id.

Currently we control alot of the article's business logic becasue we only serve a native-app from the webservice. This means we convert tags, links, images and so on in the body text of the article, into a protocol the native-app can understand. Same with alot of different attributes and data on the article, we will transform and modify its original (web) state into a state that the native-app will understand.

fx. `img` tags will be converted from a normal `<img src="http://source.com"/>` into a `<img src="inline-image//{imageId}"/>` tag, samt goes for anchor tags etc.

Now i have to implement a resource that can return the articles data in a new representation

I'm puzzled over how best to do this.

1. I could just implement a completely new resource, on a different url like: `content/articles/web/{id}` and move the old one to `content/article/app/{id}`
2. I could also specify in my documentation of the resource, that a client should always specify a specific `request header` maybe the `Accept` header for the webservice to determine which representation of the article to return.
3. I could also just use the original url, and use a `url parameter` like `.../{id}/?version=app` or `.../{id}/?version=web`

What would you guys reckon would be the best option? My personal preference lean towards option 1, simply because i think its easier to understand for clients of the webservice.

Regards, Martin.

EDIT:

I have chosen to go with option 1. Thanks for helping out and giving pros and cons. :)

Comment: It sounds like you should be using `Accept` to indicate what `Content-Type`s the requesters are interested in and using that to choose what *representation* to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose #1.  If you need to preserve the existing URLS you could add a new one `content/articles/{id}/native` or  `content/native-articles/{id}/`.  Both are REST enough.

Working with paths make content more easily cacheable than both header or param options.  Using Content-Type overcomplicates the service especially when both are returning JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This is what we have decided. I hadn't though about the complications with caching (we have a full-page varnish cache on our webservice). It made the decision easier to make.

Answer (score 2):

Use the HTTP concept of [Content Negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation). Use the `Accept` header with vendor types.

Get the articles in the *native* representation:

```
GET /api.com/content/articles/1234
Accept: application/vnd.com.exmaple.article.native+json
```

Get the articles in the  *original* representation:

```
GET /api.com/content/articles/1234
Accept: application/vnd.com.exmaple.article.orig+json
```

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 and Option 3

Both are perfectly good solutions.  I like the way Option 1 looks better, but that is just aesthetics.  It doesn't really matter.  If you choose one of these options, you should have requests to the old URL redirect to the new location using a 301.

### Option 2

This could work as well, but only if the two responses have a different Content-Type.  From the description, I couldn't really tell if this was the case.  I would not define a custom Content-Type in this case just so you could use Content Negotiation.  If the media type is not different, I would not use this option.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to the topic. We have chosen to go with option 1.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps option 2 - with the header being a Content-Type?

That seems to be the way resources are served in differing formats; e.g. XML, JSON, some custom format